# change stripe angle of background svg

Tags: css, svg, background

I´ve got a code from: [SVGeneration.com] DIAGONAL STRIPE

this:

```
function generate(inputArray){
    var scale = inputArray['scale'];
    var width = inputArray['stripe-width'];
    var background = inputArray['background'];
    var stripe = inputArray['stripe'];
    return "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='"+scale+"' height='"+scale*2+"' viewBox='0 0 5 10'>\n"+
    "   <rect width='110%' x='-5%' y='-5%' height='110%' fill='#"+background+"'/>\n"+
    "   <line x1='-2' y1='1' x2='7' y2='10' stroke='#"+stripe+"' stroke-width='"+width+"'/>\n"+
    "   <line x1='-2' y1='6' x2='7' y2='15' stroke='#"+stripe+"' stroke-width='"+width+"'/>\n"+
    "   <line x1='-2' y1='-4' x2='7' y2='5' stroke='#"+stripe+"' stroke-width='"+width+"'/>\n"+
    "</svg>";
}
```

But I don´t know How to change de angle of stripes. I would like the same angle but flip horizontal.

Could anybody help me please

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass an extra value in the inputArray parameter (e.g. flip field of type boolean). When that value is true, swap the original x1 and x2 values. For example...

```
function generate(inputArray){
    var scale = inputArray['scale'];
    var width = inputArray['stripe-width'];
    var background = inputArray['background'];
    var stripe = inputArray['stripe'];
    var flip = inputArray['flip'];
    var x1 = (flip ? 7 : -2);
    var x2 = (flip ? -2 : 7);
    return "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='"+scale+"' height='"+scale*2+"' viewBox='0 0 5 10'>\n"+
    "   <rect width='110%' x='-5%' y='-5%' height='110%' fill='#"+background+"'/>\n"+
    "   <line x1='"+x1+"' y1='1' x2='"+x2+"' y2='10' stroke='#"+stripe+"' stroke-width='"+width+"'/>\n"+
    "   <line x1='"+x1+"' y1='6' x2='"+x2+"' y2='15' stroke='#"+stripe+"' stroke-width='"+width+"'/>\n"+
    "   <line x1='"+x1+"' y1='-4' x2='"+x2+"' y2='5' stroke='#"+stripe+"' stroke-width='"+width+"'/>\n"+
    "</svg>";
}
```